# Pytorch Summary) how to calculate model size and gpu memory requirement

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I used torchinfo summary to calculate memory needed for my model

for example,if i get this summary information

what does total param means? Does it means model size is about 6GB?
and what is mult-adds?

Also, i'm curious about Estimated total size.
Does it means i need 602MB memory for one image calculation?

[(Image) torchinfo summary of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW32w.png)